# shell scripting - Extract seperated fields - field list from create field list part

Tags: shell, awk, sed, cut, tr

Input master_table_list.txt (Sample single record delimited by |)

---

```
hub_business_partner|`hash_business_partner` string COMMENT 'Surrogate Key for Business Partner', `key_business_partner` string COMMENT 'Business Key for Business Partner', `rec_srce` string COMMENT 'Record Source'|`rec_date` timestamp|key_business_partner|rec_date|COMMENT 'Business Partner Hub'|customer
```

Output needed in insert_table_preparation.txt

---

```
customer|hub_business_partner|hash_business_partner,key_business_partner,rec_srce,rec_date
```

Code Used

---

```
echo $line | awk -F'|' '{printf("'%s'\n",);}' | grep -o '`.*`'| tr -d '``' >>insert_table_preparation.txt
```

Please help me extract atleast the second field (field list).

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Malo

Comment: IMHO you've had no responses because you're asking us to look at a pile of text and print some other pile of text from it with no information on the algorithm you want to use to do the translation and the command line you already have is a mess and not something to build upon so there's no way to help you. If you [edit] your question to explain the algorithm you want help implementing that'd translate the posted input to the posted output you might get some responses.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick-and-dirty response, but this reads your example input line and produces your example output:

```
echo $line | sed -e "s/ string COMMENT[^,|]*//g" -e "s/\`//g" -e "s/, /,/g" | awk 'BEGIN{ FS = "|"; OFS = "" } { split($2, foo, ","); print $7, "|", $1, "|", foo[1], ",", foo[2], ",", foo[3], "|", $5 }'
```

Comment: Hi Leslie, your above "dirty little" response is working fine. Thank you. However, if the field names vary in number, is there any generic way to seperate them? It seems we are using foo[1], foo[2] etc. Can there be something like foo[i] to make solution more generic? Thank you again for your efforts.

Comment: Malo, glad my response was useful.  The split function returns the number of fields in the array it creates, so you could do something like  

    k = split($2, foo, ","); 
    for ( i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        print foo[i];